# How i can Call the Deletage Methods Procedures in a Normal Proc?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Please Help

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
     UiTextField Delegate Method...
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
}


- (IBAction)iButton:(id)sender {
   // how i can call here -(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField)
}
```

Comment: if you have an outlet myTextfield for your textfield, you can call [self textFieldDidBeginEditing:self.myTextfield];

Comment: Take IBOutlet of your textfield and write [textField becomeFirstResponder]; it will call this delegate method directly with your outlet textfield.

Comment: i try write a Tweak on Theos for Activator Method.. 

I have Example Project , there a UiAllertViewDelegate...

But i should paste a Text with Activator Method.. there in Project is also a Delegate Method.. 

Procedure Activator {

if home button 3time click , paste text , where is cursor...

{

Answer (score 0):

you can by either ,

1. [self textFieldDidBeginEditing:nil];

if you need to pass the textfield as well create an IBOutlet for the respective textfield and call it like ,

1. [self textFieldDidBeginEditing:self.myTextField];

Comment: i Write now
        
     
        
        
 }
}

Comment: oh thanx for Answer but i try  a tweak for iPhone for Activator method..
Activator method begin here ....

- (void)activator:(LAActivator *)activator receiveEvent:(LAEvent *)event
{
 // Called when we recieve event
 if (![self dismiss]) {
 
        
    if use Event from Activator , it should paste text on Anyyone Textfield on Springboard where is the cursor .. But Activator Method is Delegate method and textfiel is also a Delegate method. I cant call it


        
 }
}